# Check if input number is valid in Codeigniter Form Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can you help me to validate if my input number is valid.

It can be a whole number 
It can also be a decimal number but interval is 0.5, So 0.5, 1.5 , 2.5 is ok but .2,1.3,2.6 is not valid.

```
if ((preg_match('/^\d+\.\d+$/',$bkpoints))  || (preg_match('/^\.\d+$/',$bkpoints)))
{       {
    if ($bkpoints % 0.5 !== 0)
    {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('is_bk_decimal','Bk points decimal value should be incremented by 0.5');
          return false;
    }

 }
 return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate it with one single regex `^\d+(?:\.[05]0*)?$` :

```
if(preg_match('#^\d+(?:\.[05]0*)?$#', $bkpoints)){
    echo 'valid';
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` : begin of line
- `\d+` : match a digit one or more times
- `(?:` : start of non-capturing group

  - `\.` : match a dot
  - `[05]` : match `0` or `5`
  - `0` : match `0` zero or more times
- `)`: End of non-capturing group
- `?` : make the group optional
- `$` : end of line

<kbd>[**online regex demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lR9iA7)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks much, Actually We are almost there but when I input 0.5 it also gave invalid. 0.5 should also be accepted

Comment: @user2046410 impossibruuuu [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/bS1yB9) | [php demo](http://ideone.com/jaC5mP). Make sure you don't have spaces etc...

Comment: I edit it like this  if((preg_match('#^\d+(?:\.[05]0*)?$#', $bkpoints)) || (preg_match('#^(?:\.[05]0*)?$#', $bkpoints))){ and it works fine for. Thank you very much for the idea HamZa

Comment: @user2046410 You could wrap everything in one single regex `^\d+(?:\.[05]0*)?$|^(?:\.[05]0*)$` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tS8hM7). What you have will even match empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `is_numeric()` function in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

It'd return true if the number is an valid number, and return false if it isn't.

Comment: ah yes but it will not check if its interval of 0.5

Comment: I'm sorry, check my other answer below ;)

Answer (score -1):

Or you could also use the `ereg()` function:

```
if(ereg("^([0-9]+|[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*)(.[0-9]{1,2})?$", "0.9")){
  echo "number";
}else{
  echo "not a number";
}
```

Comment: Update your existing answer, don't post a second one... also: `ereg` is _DEPRECATED_, use `preg_match` instead. Lastly: regular expressions to check if a value is a float is just total overkill